# how does subtracting works in macro definition

Tags: c++11

why does C = 2 shouldn't it be 0 A+1 = 1 and 1-B =0 how does it work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define A 0
#define B A+1
#define C 1-B

int main()
{
 cout << C ;
}
```

Comment: Macros work by substituting text, they do not perform any arithmetic. Take a look at the preprocessor output and it should become clear.  Doing `cc -E filename.cpp` on a linux machine will show you the preprocessor output.

Comment: Will do thank you very much

Comment: Once you figure it out, post it here as an answer to your own question. You might find this page helpful: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lakshay Garg i understand what he means it just replaces the Macro with whatever i define so in the case of "#define C 1-B" the B will be replaced with A+1 which is 0+1
So in in my cout C= 1-0+1 Which is 2 again thanks for the help